# Unable to find field "Netid" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I looked at other posts regarding this and attempted all tips to fix it but am still getting the error. Can someone look at my code and give me an idea on why this I continue to get this error.

The .html code looks like

```
<% provide(:title, "Log in") %>
<h1>Log in</h1>

<h2>Note: authentication currently supports both a TAMU NetID or the use of CAS.</h2>
<h2>To access the CAS authentication system, click <%= link_to "here", new_member_session_path %></h2> <br />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :netid %>
      <%= f.text_field :username, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

  </div>
</div>
```

My test looks like

```
Background: 
  Given I am on the home page 
  When I follow "Login"
  And I fill in "Netid" with "admin"
  And I press "Log in"
```

I have trie:

```
"Netid"
"Member[netid]"
"Member[:netid]"
":netid"
"netid"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're telling Capybara to fill in the label instead of the input field.

Spin up your Rails app locally and view the source for that page. You should see the field look something like `<input type="text" id="session_username" name="session[username]" class="form-control" />`.

Try changing "Netid" to the value you see for the id or name there.

Comment: @KateGodfrey The root cause there is that your label isn't actually associated with the text field -- you probably want something like `f.label :username, 'NetID'` which would then allow you to do `fill_in 'NetID', with: 'admin'` since the label would actually be associated with the username text field via a `for` attribute.

Comment: @DylanReile I have another quick question. When i press "Log in" and then checking what I should see on the next page it does not work. It gives me what is on the page and it is still the login page rather than the page after. Is is different because it is a form?

Comment: @KateGodfrey I'm assuming this form posts and hits the create action on a sessions_controller? At the end of the create method you'll need to `redirect_to` the path or `render` the view of the "page after".